# How can you pass anonymous functions as parameters to existing functions to use later in javascript?

Tags: javascript, jquery, anonymous-function

I am trying to create a basic javascript framework that you can pass different things into, including functions for it to execute later.  Right now, I'm in a more simple testing phase, but I can't quite get the function calling to work.  A piece of my code is here:

[My JS Fiddle][1]http://jsfiddle.net/mp243wm6/

My code has an object that holds different data, and I want to call the method later, but with data that is available at the time of creation.  Here is a code snippet of the function that uses the function that is passed to the object:

```
clickMe : function() {
        this.obj.click(function() {
            this.func();
        });
    }
```

Any suggestions or things I should read are welcome.

Comment: `this` is not what you think it is. It is not about the function itself, it is about how the function gets called.

Comment: You can use this structure, but you have to be very careful about the value of `this`.  `this` is determined by how the function is called, not by how it is declared.  Here, the value of `this` in your callback will determined by the `.click()` function and will likely not be what you want.  You can use `.bind()` on your anonymous function that you pass if you want to control `this` yourself.

Comment: See [this helpful section](http://bonsaiden.github.io/JavaScript-Garden/#function.this) of the [Javascript Zen Garden](http://bonsaiden.github.io/JavaScript-Garden/) page for more details on how `this` works.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that there're two different contexts:

```
clickMe : function() {
    // here is one
    this.obj.click(function() {
        // here is another
        this.func();
    });
}
```

You can simple pass the function as parameter, like the following:

```
clickMe : function() {
    this.obj.click($.proxy(this.func, this));
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/mp243wm6/2/

Comment: Your second example won't have `this` set properly in `func`.

Comment: Awesome - that helps a ton!  I don't know why I didn't think about passing it in like that, but it makes sense (from all the other comments - thank you) why [this] wouldn't mean the same thing within the click method.

Comment: @jfriend00 Ohhh sure, you're completely right. Fixed it.

Comment: @NicholausChipping Take a look the following, http://jsfiddle.net/mp243wm6/3/. When you click the text.

Comment: Could also use: `this.obj.click(this.func.bind(this));`.

Answer (score 1):

**The problem:**

Considering your code in the JSFiddle, you have:

```
onClick : function() {
    this.obj.click(function() {                
        this.func();
    });
},
```

As noted, you have different contexts going on here.

Consider the snippet `this.obj.click(function() { this.func(); })`. The first `this` here is a reference to the framework.events object. The second `this` here is a reference to whatever will be `this` when this function get called. In the case of your JSFiddle, when `this.func` gets called, `this` is actually the DOM object that represents the `<div id="test">TEST</div>` node. Since it doesn't have a `func` function, calling `func()` on it causes:

> Uncaught TypeError: undefined is not a function

You have to understand the following: you have to pass the correct `this` in which you want the function `func` to be called.

**The solution:**

A couple of ways to make it work as you would like:

**1. with bind**

`this.obj.click(this.func.bind(this));`

This way, you are telling: "call my `this.func` function, but make sure that it will be called using the `this` that I am passing as a parameter". Vanilla JS, no $.proxy stuff.

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/mp243wm6/5/)

**2. with a copy of the reference to the actual function**

```
onClick : function() {
    var theFunctionReference = this.func;
    this.obj.click(function() {
        theFunctionReference();
    });
},
```

This way, you will not rely on the value of `this` outside of the context of the framework.events object.

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/mp243wm6/6/)

Answer (score 0):

The issue is that this is not bound to the correct object. I would suggest you look into Function.bind() because that creates a function with this pointing to the right thing.